New CSS Anchor Positioning API and `::selection` CSS pseudo-element: Using selection as anchor?
I am looking at the new CSS Anchor Positioning API. Can I use the CSS anchor positioning API to place a tooltip over the currently selected text?
I tried to achieve this with the ::selection CSS pseudo-element but that doesn't seem to work (example below). Other pseudo class do not work either (e.g. ::after).
Questions

I assume CSS Anchor Positioning API does not work with pseudo-elements. Is that correct?
Are there other solutions what would allow me to use selected text as an anchor?

Note: I am testing in Chrome 125, which supports the CSS Anchor Positioning API. At this point, other browsers do not.
Here is an example.
<div class="anchor">
  <p>This is some random text. This is some random text. This is some random text. This is some random text. This is some random text.</p>
</div>

<div class="anchored-notice">
  <p>I am a tooltip<p>
</div>

Using a div element as the anchor works...
.anchor {
  anchor-name: --anchor-el;
}

.anchored-notice {
  background-color:#f00;
  position: absolute;
  position-anchor: --anchor-el;
  top: anchor(bottom);
  right: anchor(right);
}

Using text selection via ::selection as anchor does not
p::selection {
  anchor-name: --anchor-el;
}

.anchored-notice {
  background-color:#f00;
  position: absolute;
  position-anchor: --anchor-el;
  top: anchor(bottom);
  right: anchor(right);
}


Only certain CSS properties can be used with ::selection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection#allowable_properties
